# Is it possible to heal war allies in Stellaris using my infrastructure?

Tags: stellaris

I've got a lot of allied fleets waiting in my home system to make an offensive push. But some of them are pretty low on hull points and I want to heal them up before we leave. They're orbiting my planet and that's not healing them and I also tried leasing them to a healing aura from a defense station nearby. I'm at a loss as to how to heal them? Is there a tech I need or something?

Comment: Defines "allies".  Are you part of a federation? Or are you and your ally simply two empires that are at war with a common enemy (and not each other)?